# Redirecting Certain Requests into Subdir with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm launching a new site on WordPress but would like all of my old links to remain active. To make this possible I've moved my present site into a subdirectory (/oldsite) and installed the new wordpress site directly in root.

How would I go about redirectin any url that matches the old path style into the /oldsite directory so that:

`http://example.com/stories/read/4231/some-story-title`

is automatically redirected to

`http://example.com/oldsite/stories/read/4231/some-story-title`

The same would go for many other domain patterns like:

`http://example.com/exclusives` becoming `http://example.com/oldsite/exclusives` and a few more.

I don't want all requests to go into the /oldsite directory, since I will rely onmy WordPress instance in root.

.htaccess is still somewhat cryptic to me, so I would appreciate any direction.

Comment: Then what kind of requests do you want being redirected?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Gumbo, I'm not sure I understand. I'm just trying to redirect all visitors to the site who are expecting the old content into the subdirectory where the old content now resides.

Comment: How to distinguish between those paths that should be redirected and those that shouldn’t? Is there a pattern for that, e.g. a common prefix or something else?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. It's a case by case issue. `/exclusives`, `/cartoons` and `/story` are the only paths I can think of right now that need to be redirected. From these, I'm sure I could modify the code to include others if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(stories|exclusives)/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /oldsite/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This looks simple enough. Could you explain the `[NC]`, `[R]`, and `[L]`?

Comment: NC is case insensitive, R is redirect (with the 301 being the redirect HTTP response code to use) and L is "last rule", e.g. stop trying to match any more rules for this request.  See all the options here - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /oldsite/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

It will not actually redirect .. It will internally run from oldsite folder

If u want to redirect then add `[R=301,L]` to `RewriteRule`